# HTML5 JS - How do I make my bullets/shots go in a constant direction?

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

I've been struggling with the bullet code for a while now. I know there is most likely a simpler solution (in fact I recall something similar I've done before, but I just can't remember it). But anyway;

PROBLEM: My bullets fire in all 4 directions, as they should. However if I choose to move after firing, in a different direction, the direction, and position, of the bullets will also change.

For example, if I am facing up and fire 3 bullets, then travel to the right, the bullets will change direction and velocity with me, instead I want it to continue travelling in that direction as I move in a different direction.

Here is the code for the bullets;

```
    function Bullet(w, h, s){
        this.x = tank.x;
        this.y = tank.y
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.speed = s; 
    }

    //setInterval of firing

    function setFire(){
        tankCanFire = true;
    }

    //Create a new bullet

    function fireBullet(){
        if(tankCanFire){
            tankCanFire = false;
                bullets.push(new Bullet(5, 10, 15));    


                ctx.fillText("Ding", 300, 300);
            }
        }

    //DRAW the Bullets + velocities.

    function drawBullet(){

            ctx.fillText("length = " +bullets.length, 200, 200); 


        if (bullets.length > 0){

            for (var key in bullets)
            {
                    ctx.fillText("DONG", 200, 250);

                    if (tank.up == true) 
                    {               
                    ctx.drawImage(bulletImage, bullets[key].x + 13, bullets[key].y - 8);
                    bullets[key].y -= 15;   

                        if (bullets[key].y < 0) 
                            delete bullets[key];


                    }

                    else if (tank.down == true)
                    {               
                    ctx.drawImage(bulletImage, bullets[key].x + 13, bullets[key].y + 40);
                    bullets[key].y += 15;   

                        if (bullets[key].y > 400)
                            delete bullets[key];

                    }

                    else if (tank.left == true)
                    {               
                    ctx.drawImage(bulletImage, bullets[key].x - 8, bullets[key].y + 13);
                    bullets[key].x -= 15;   

                        if (bullets[key].x < 0)
                            delete bullets[key];

                    }

                    else if (tank.right == true)
                    {               
                    ctx.drawImage(bulletImage, bullets[key].x + 40, bullets[key].y + 13);
                    bullets[key].x += 15;   

                        if (bullets[key].x > 600)
                            delete bullets[key];

                    }               
            }                   
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bullet, in addition to x,y,width,height,speed you also need to store the direction this particular bullet is going. The current code will look at the tank's orientation when moving the bullet, so the bullet's direction will change if you turn the tank. This can be fun too, but if you want traditional bullets it makes sense to store, in the bullet, the direction it's going.

The easiest way to do this is to store, not the speed, but the velocity. Something like this:

```
function Bullet(w, h, dx, dy){
    this.x = tank.x;
    this.y = tank.y
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.dx = dx; // how much x changes at every time step 
    this.dy = dy;
}
```